# Filtring csv file datas and save them another csv file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter

I have a .csv file that has data like that:

```
index, name,    id
1      john     512
2      Anne     895
3      Angel    897
4      Lusia    777
```

So I want to filter them by name endings and get names only which have vowel endings. And the result must be like that:

```
    index, name,     id
    1      Anne     895
    2      Lusia    777
```

After filtering, I want to save the result in another .csv file. I am trying various ways to get the correct result, However, I could not do that. please help me :(

Comment: use `pandas.read_csv` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` to read and write csv files. For selection you can use something like `df[df.name.str[-1].apply(lambda x: x in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])]`

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please edit your question and include some code that you've tried, and any errors. If not errors, please share the output that is not working.

Comment: I am a newbie in python that's why can not make the correct code. if you have any solutions for this. please share there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying before asking questions helps improve coding skills

```py
import csv


def read_csv(filename, outfile="res.csv"):
    vowel = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}
    with open(filename, 'r') as f, open(outfile, 'w', newline="") as out:
        out.write(f.readline())        # write header
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)   # space-separate and skip extra spaces
        writer = csv.writer(out)      # csv write object

        # Filter out lines that don't end with a vowel
        writer.writerows(line for line in reader if line[1][-1] in vowel) 


read_csv("a.csv", outfile="res.csv")
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 285: character maps to <undefined>